# Selenium Javascript Wait

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I'm trying to use selenium-webdriver in Node to crawl Google finance pages. The driver.wait function does not appear to work as expected. I have set my mocha timeout to be 10 seconds and the driver.wait timeout be 9 seconds. The test passes about half of the time, but when it fails, it doesn't take anywhere near 9 seconds to fail - it actually fails in about 1 second and then takes another 8 before closing the test. I'm obviously missing something, but I've included the commented-out iterations of different things I've tried in order to make this work (including setTimeout). If anyone can help me see the error in my thinking, I would be much obliged. Here's the code:

```
(function () {
    var assert = require("chai").assert;
    var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
    var urlGoogleFinanceRoot = "https://www.google.com/finance";

describe("Selenium", function () {
    it("should fetch a couple of pages and keep all of the content", function (done) {
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
        webdriver.promise.controlFlow().on("uncaughtException", function (e) {
            console.error("Error1: " + e);
        });
        // driver.get(urlGoogleFinanceRoot + "?q=BAC").then(function () {
        //  return setTimeout(function () {
        //      return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//table[@class='snap-data']")).isDisplayed();
        //  }, 9000).then(function (isDisplayed) {
        //      assert.isTrue(isDisplayed);
        //      driver.quit();
        //      done();
        //  });
        // });

        // driver.wait(function () {
        //  return driver.get(urlGoogleFinanceRoot + "?q=BAC").then(function () {
        //      return driver.wait(function () {
        //          return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//table[@class='snap-data']")).isDisplayed();
        //      }, 9000);
        //  });
        // }, 9000).then(function (isDisplayed) {
        //  assert.isTrue(isDisplayed);
        //  driver.quit();
        //  done();
        // });
        // driver.wait(function(){
        //  return driver.get(urlGoogleFinanceRoot + "?q=BAC").then(function(){
        //      return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//table[@class='snap-data']")).isDisplayed();
        //  });
        // },5000).then(function(isDisplayed){
        //  assert.isTrue(isDisplayed);
        //  driver.quit();
        //  done();
        // });
        driver.get(urlGoogleFinanceRoot + "?q=BAC").then(function () {
            driver.wait(function () {
                return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//table[@class='snap-data']")).isDisplayed();
            }, 9000).then(function (isReady) {
                assert.isTrue(isReady);
                driver.quit();
                done();
            });
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

and here's the output:

```
  Selenium
Error1: NoSuchElementError: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.107)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243      (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64  x86_64)
    1) should fetch a couple of pages and keep all of the content


  0 passing (10s)
  1 failing

  1) Selenium should fetch a couple of pages and keep all of the content:
     Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from this [doc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html#wait) I understand that when you provide a function, it waits until the promise is resolved, but guessing that it is run only once, so you gotto try something like:

```
    driver.get(urlGoogleFinanceRoot + "?q=BAC").then(function () {
        driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.xpath("//table[@class='snap-data']")), 9000)
          .then(...
```